# If you upload app to Play Account and Publish to BETA testing

Tags: android, google-play

If you just upload an app to your play developer account, then submitted it for BETA testing:

1 - Is the app actually published

2 - Is the app released on Play store

3 - Do the policies relating to Play Store published (released) apps still apply to BETA versions, bearing in mind its private usage only and the app is still in developement and not beed finalized.

Answer (score 1):

1) Yes

2) Yes but it's only visible for people you've added to your beta group

3) Yes I believe so.

Answer (score 0):

Otherwise you can upload it in alpha. Just few users (testers) could download it.

Comment: whats difference between alpha and beta